# How to import Java class-files from another workspace of a different PC

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to import class-files from my PC to my Laptop. I use on both Eclipse and Windows 10 and tried to put the files in the other workspace. It didn`t work. Is there any easy, fast option to import the files.

By the way when I try to import the file manually I get the error **"The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput')."**

Comment: The most efficient solution in order to work on a project using more computers is a code storing service as gitHub. Every time you must change workstation, just pull repository

Comment: Do you mean .class files or .java files? Classes need to be put on the classpath and the easiest way to handle them would be by bundling them i a jar. Source files (i.e. .java) need to be put into a source folder and into a directory structure that reflects their package. The easiest way to handle those would be to move the entire project and to import that - ideally use a version control system such as Git (have a look at github) to share the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go on working with your eclipse project to another location you need to migrate all resources, not just the class files. To migrate a project, you can right-click on the project and hit "Export->Archive File". In the following wizard you can select projects and resources that you want to transport to another workspace.

[image: export]

In the new location you select "Import->Existing projects into workspace". In the following wizard, choose "Select archive file" and select your file, then you can choose the projects to import.

[image: import]

[image: import2]

Of course, as stated in the comments, if you want to be able to work in both places and not migrate altogether, using a version control system such as git is highly preferable, because otherwise you would have to keep these projects in sync manually.